# Concatenate with requirejs and exclude a single file?

Tags: javascript, text, requirejs, concatenation

I have build and app using requirejs and use it to load html templates and a single config file via the text plugin.

After concatenation the html templates are inlined in the JS, which is fine, but I need the config.json file to still remain as a file which is loaded externally like before concatenation.

Example code of the main view

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'lib/text!templates/main.html',
'lib/text!config.json',
], function($, _, Backbone, projectListTemplate, Config) {
    var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({});
})
```

This is my build file

```
({
appDir: './../public',
baseUrl: 'static/js/app',
dir: './../dist',

modules: [
    {
        name: 'main'
    }
],
fileExclusionRegExp: /^(r|build)\.js$/,
exclude: ['config.json'],
optimizeCss: 'standard',
removeCombined: true,
paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-2.0.3.min',
    waypoints: 'lib/waypoints.min',
    underscore: 'lib/underscore',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone',
    text: 'lib/text',
},
shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: [
            'underscore',
            'jquery',
            'waypoints'
        ],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
}
})
```

Comment: Hi Summer, do you know the solution to your problem now? I am facing the same problem. Please let me know the solution, if you have.

Comment: @DheerajKumarAggarwal posted an answer, if you are still interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exclude your file in the same way you included it. Try this way:

```
exclude: ['lib/text!config.json']
```

But I just stopped using this approach, because it requires existence of config.json file in build phase. Instead I'm using nested require calls (You may use require inside your `define`d modules to load files in runtime). Unlike `define`, nested `require` may not be included in build process (and by default they are not) and validation phase will be fine.

Be advised, this approach has at least one **disadvantage**:

**Nested require calls are also asynchronous.** But in my case that is not a problem.

Comment: The problem with that solution is require.js do not include the json! extension and try to load /json.js do you think there is an other solution to exclude the json but keep the extension ?

Comment: @ValEntin, by using the `excludeShallow` option instead of `exclude` in your build configuration, you will keep the plugin, but exclude the JSON files.